# How can I run a Curl command from Jenkins A in order to trigger a build in Jenkins B

Tags: jenkins, curl, triggers

I want to trigger a build in Jenkins B by running build in Jenkins A, I know that I can use a Curl command from Jenkins A but actually I couldn't figure it how and where to write the command, inside the pipeline or as power-shell script?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://isignal.github.io/notes/jenkins-cli.html)  is described how it works.

1. You need to download the jenkins-cli.jar from the jenkins server you want to trigger a job on.

   ```
   wget http://YOUR_JENKINS_HOSTNAME/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
   ```
2. You have to verify that you can authenticate to the jenkins server.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa && cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   Copy the public key to `http://YOUR_JENKINS_HOSTNAME/user/YOUR_USERNAME/configure`. On the same page you can generate a API Token. You will need it for the remote call. You can save it as file with the following command:

   ```
   echo 'YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_API_TOKEN' > jenkins_secret
   ```
3. Now you can call the remote jenkins server and trigger builds

   ```
   java -jar ./jenkins-cli.jar -s http://YOUR_JENKINS_HOSTNAME list-jobs
   ```

To integrate it to your pipeline just add a `sh` step and take the last line (the jenkins-cli.jar call) and add it to your pipeline.